# Re-render view from FormCollection after an validation failure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a submission page that will post to an action controller & this action controller accepts `FormCollection` Object only (cause of the dynamic nature of this page).

Now there is a business validation is done over the values received in the FormCollection, My question is, when i found an error in one of the values I have to re-render the view with the values received in the form collection (How to do so???)

Comment: Is your `ViewModel` a `FormCollection` as well?

Comment: No, the viewmodel is strongly typed class contain list of question class, & in the view i'm rendering each question based on its type to be input, select, file, ....         also each html element in the form has the name equals question id, so in server side i know which value correspond to which question answer

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the FormCollection then store the value in a `ViewData`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{
     foreach ( string key in collection.AllKeys )
     {
          ViewData[key] = collection[key];   
     }

     return View()

}
```

Then I think you have to type the input fields one by one

**View**

```
<input name="address" value="@ViewData["address"]" />
<input name="mobile" value="@ViewData["mobile"]" />
```